# How to have an alert message if back button is pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a number of inputs in a form and I want to open an alert pop up window only after an input field is edited. How can I manage it?

What I have done in previous is, whenever I open the edit page, I am just checking the length, if it’s greater than zero I am giving an alert.

But now I need to get alert only when I stroke any key and press back button. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: try `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; };`

Comment: forget about the key stroke. check the data before and after when you click the back button. if the data has changed then do as the above comment mentions

Comment: Note that `onbeforeunload` will trigger on reload, and any other instance of leaving the page

Comment: yea.. But i need to check whether the data is changed..But the form inputs are more..each has different classes.. then how to check everything at once and give alert

Comment: Why does it matter? If the user presses the back button, they implicitly know that they will lose their data and clearly wish to do so. You shouldn't break browser functionality/expected usability with script.

Comment: But in edit functionality , i must enter something..only after that i need to give an alert

Comment: @ManoDestra This is not and ***should*** not always the case. Sometimes, it is important to protect a user from themselves. Accidents happen. For instance, I myself have accidentally hit backspace when I thought a field was in focus and wasn't, or swiped left with my mouse and found myself having to repeat data. I know this can be prevented by simply being careful, but not everyone shares the same mindset.

Comment: Still shouldn't be breaking expected browser protocol, by interjecting with back button functionality. Reasonably protection against loss of data is fine, but don't mess with the expected usability of the browser. It's a standard no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page/document first loads, create a variable that keeps track of the current state of various the input fields, E.g

> `window.unsaved = false`.

When a user presses any key on any of your input fields (check this using an event listener, or if you're using jquery, by using the keydown event), changed `unsaved` to be `true`. Within `onbeforeunload`, check to see if unsaved == true and if it is, display your alert.

**If using jQuery,** you could do something like;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // put this next variable in the global scope (window.) so you can
  // access it from unload

  window.unsaved == false; 

  $('input').keydown(function(){
    window.unsaved == true;
  })
})

$( window ).unload(function() {
  if(window.unsaved == true){
    alert('You have unsaved work.');
  }
});
```